# Texture loaded with THREE.TextureLoader() is not well mapped on a THREE.ExtrudeGeometry geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I am creating a rounded vertices domino using a rounded rectangle THREE.Shape then extruded via THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.
I then load a texture from an image (rectangular brick wall) and apply it to this geometry's front face.
I was expecting the wall to fit the face of my rounded rectangle but instead I get the result of the picture below:
[Texture mapping issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpPXB.jpg)

Is it a THREEJS bug or did I miss something?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
Below is the code I used:

```js
//add tile
var tile_size = 2;
var roundedRectShape = new THREE.Shape();
  ( function roundedRect( ctx, x, y, width, height, radius ) {
    ctx.moveTo( x, y + radius );
    ctx.lineTo( x, y + height - radius );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y + height, x + radius, y + height );
    ctx.lineTo( x + width - radius, y + height );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius );
    ctx.lineTo( x + width, y + radius );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + width, y, x + width - radius, y );
    ctx.lineTo( x + radius, y );
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, x, y + radius );
  } )( roundedRectShape, 0, 0, 1.5*tile_size, 1.7*tile_size, 0.1 );
var extrudeSettings = {
  steps: 3,
  depth: 0.1*tile_size,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelThickness: 0.05,
  bevelSize: 0.05,
  bevelSegments: 3
};
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( roundedRectShape, extrudeSettings );
  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "content/wall.jpg" );

  var materialFace = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      map: texture
  });
  var materialSide = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: '#EEEBDC'
  });
  var materials = [materialFace, materialSide];

tile = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
tile.rotation.x = - Math.PI/2;
tile.position.z = -1;
tile.position.x = -0.5*tile_size/2;
tile.position.y = -0.2*tile_size;

all.add( tile );
```

Answer (score 0):

When UV mapping, you should keep your values in the range from 0 to 1. `ExtrudeGeometry` assigns UVs based on the vertex positions. So if you have a vertex at `[4, 3, -2]`, its corresponding UV value would be `[4, 3]`. Anything beyond 1 will "stretch" (or repeat, depending on your texture parameters).

**You could either:**

1. Try drawing your `tileSize` somewhere between the range of `[0, 1]` so your UV Mapping fits within the desired range. You could then scale the whole tile Mesh with `tile.scale.set(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)`

or

2. You could make your texture repeat infinitely with `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping`. You could see alternative wrapping modes in the [texture constants page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Textures)